# 正規表現の書き方

Tags: php

以下のような文字列で
/category/tops/knit-sweater/
最後の/ から　その前の/までの文字（この場合だと　knit-sweater）を取得したいのですが、
どのように正規表現を書けば実現できますでしょうか。

詳しい方、ご教示ください。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 3):

pathから最後の名前を取り出す為に`basename`という関数が用意されています。

```
$ php -r 'echo basename("/category/tops/knit-sweater/");'
```

Answer (score 2):

個人的には正規表現を使うほどでもないかなと思います。
下記では駄目でしょうか？

```
$str = '/category/tops/knit-sweater/';
$expArray = explode('/', $str);

$index = count($expArray) - 2; // 最後の一個前のインデックス
$hosiiStr = $expArray[$index];
```

Answer (score 1):

サンプルが少ないので、意図を読み間違えているかもしれませんが、とりあえずこれで目的は果たせるように思います。

```
$str = '/category/tops/knit-sweater/';
$pattern = '#/([^/]*)/$#';
$matches = [];
if( preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches) ) {
  print($matches[1]); //->knit-sweater
}
```

最後の`/`の後ろにまだ何か文字が入る可能性があるなど、細かい部分で微調整が必要になる可能性はありますが、最後の何かを取り出したいのであれば、多くの場合に`$`が使えると思います。